# How can I remove the indentation of just one item in an enumeration?

Tags: enumerate, itemize

The title explains almost everything.
I am nesting enumerations. Also, since I want to write content about specific items, I am interrupting the enumerations to insert framed text. This requires the packages `framed` and `enumitem`. Currently, I'm able to generate this:

[image]

The code for the minimum working example is this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}
  \def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
  \item First item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \def\labelenumii{\arabic{enumii}.}
    \item Another item
    \item Yet another foo item
    \end{enumerate} % TASK COMMENT SECTION
        \begin{framed}
            \textcolor{red}{This section be aligned to the left side of the box}
        \end{framed}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \def\labelenumii{\arabic{enumii}.}
    \item Foo item
    \end{enumerate}
      \begin{framed}
          \textcolor{red}{This section should also be aligned to the left side of the box.}
      \end{framed}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \def\labelenumii{\arabic{enumii}.}
    \item Foo foo item
    \item Bar item

    \begin{enumerate}
    \def\labelenumiii{\arabic{enumiii}.}
    \item Nested item
    \item Second nested item
    \end{enumerate}

      \begin{framed} % TASK COMMENT SECTION
      \noindent
          Bla bla to explain the reasons of this enumerations.\\
          \textcolor{red}{EVERYTHING ON THIS BOX SHOULD HAVE A NORMAL LEFT ALIGNMENT.}\\
          \underline{Mock title}
          \begin{itemize}
            \item A deeply embedded foo
            \item Another deeply embedded foo
          \end{itemize}
          \underline{Gosh, no more mock titles please!}
          \begin{itemize}
           \item Bored foo
           \item Yet another bored foo
          \end{itemize}
            \underline{Shameful copy of the last enum}
          \begin{itemize}
           \item Bored foo
           \item Yet another bored foo
          \end{itemize}
      \end{framed}
      \begin{enumerate}[resume]
      \def\labelenumiii{\arabic{enumiii}.}

      \item Almost finished
      \item Finished
      \end{enumerate}
    \item Oh, not yet??
    \item At the end
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{framed} % TASK COMMENT SECTION
        I promise this is the last box \textcolor{red}{THAT SHOULD BE ALIGNED TO THE LEFT!}
    \end{framed}

    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \def\labelenumiii{\arabic{enumiii}.}

    \item This one is not well numbered because I got lost in the freakish nesting of enums, but you get the idea.
    \end{enumerate}

  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The text inside the frames is being indented, my guess is that it is taking the expected indentation for an item on his `enumerate` section.

1. How can I remove the indent of the item in which the frame is
   located?
2. Is it possible to avoid the indentation of a single item on
   an enumeration?

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal working example (MWE) to your problem, which is compilable including all necessary packages and beginning at `\documentclass`, ending at `\end{document}`

Comment: @Skillmon done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution (I think) for the updated question. I define a `listcomment` environment, with one optional argument, the difference between the current list level and `first level`. Default is `1`. I took the opportunity to simplify your code, using the `\setlist` command.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{0.5em}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{label =\arabic*., wide =0pt, leftmargin = *}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label =\arabic*., wide, leftmargin = *}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{changepage}
\newenvironment{listcomment}[1][1]{\framed\adjustwidth{-\dimexpr #1\leftmargin + \fontdimen2\font}{}}{\endadjustwidth\endframed}

\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First item\\
    Firstitem
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Another item
    \item Yet another foo item
    \end{enumerate} % TASK COMMENT SECTION
        \begin{listcomment}
        \color{red} This section should be aligned to the left side of the box. This section should be aligned to the a left side of the box.
        \end{listcomment}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item Foo item
    \end{enumerate}
      \begin{listcomment}
       \color{red} This section should also be aligned to the left side of the box.
      \end{listcomment}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item Foo foo item
    \item Bar item

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Nested item
    \item Second nested item
    \end{enumerate}

      \begin{listcomment}[2] % TASK COMMENT SECTION
      \noindent
          Bla bla to explain the reasons of this enumerations.\\
          \textcolor{red}{EVERYTHING ON THIS BOX SHOULD HAVE A NORMAL LEFT ALIGNMENT.}\\
          \underline{Mock title}
          \begin{itemize}
            \item A deeply embedded foo
            \item Another deeply embedded foo
          \end{itemize}
          \underline{Gosh, no more mock titles please!}
          \begin{itemize}
           \item Bored foo
           \item Yet another bored foo
          \end{itemize}
            \underline{Shameful copy of the last enum}
          \begin{itemize}
           \item Bored foo
           \item Yet another bored foo
          \end{itemize}
      \end{listcomment}
      \begin{enumerate}[resume]

      \item Almost finished
      \item Finished
      \end{enumerate}
    \item Oh, not yet??
    \item At the end
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{listcomment} % TASK COMMENT SECTION
        I promise this is the last box \textcolor{red}{THAT SHOULD BE ALIGNED TO THE LEFT!}
    \end{listcomment}

    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item This one is not well numbered because I got lost in the freakish nesting of enums, but you get the idea.
    \end{enumerate}

  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for being interested!. I have updated the question

Comment: @JPCF: I've changed my answer to satisfy your requirements. Is that OK now?

Comment: fulfills the requirement to completion! thanks for your time!...