# Limit tcolorbox to the width of the page

Tags: enumerate, tcolorbox, width

[In another thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382920/define-custom-environment) I asked for a little help with setting up an own `solution` environment to use in student assignment-sheets.

We there checked a boolean (if it's the solution sheet or only the assignment sheet for the students) and if the boolean returns to `true`, the answers inside the `solution` environment are printed. (Code is inside the MWE)

As the questions are set up in an `enumerate` environment, the questions and the answers are indented.
The little issue I now have, is that the solution-container (a `tcolorbox`) is wider than the `linewidth`. If I indent a second time it's even bigger...

How can I restrict this environment to the real `\linewidth`?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% %%%
% Packages
% %%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose, a4paper, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm, lmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm} 
\usepackage{lipsum, enumerate, ifthen, tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}



% %%%
% Variable Settings
% %%%%
\newboolean{solution}
\setboolean{solution}{true}



% %%%
% Environments / Commandy
% %%%%
\newcommand{\Problem}[1]{
    {
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \textsf{\textbf{Problem #1}}
        \vspace*{0.2cm}
    }
}

\newenvironment{solution}
{
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{
        \tcolorbox[breakable, width=\textwidth, colframe=red, colback=white]
    }{}
}
{
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{
        \endtcolorbox
        \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    }{}
}



% %%%
% Document
% %%%%
\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \LARGE \sf \textbf{MWE}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{0.2cm}

    \Problem{1: Foo}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
            \begin{solution}
                \lipsum[4-5]
            \end{solution}

            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
                    \begin{solution}
                        \lipsum[4-4]
                    \end{solution}
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

I used the `showframe` attribute of the `geometry`-package to show the real `\linewidth` and where my environment is. It's clear, that the overlapping is exactly the same as the indention of the enumerate.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You might add the link to the other thread...

Comment: @Skillmon Done!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your question you already talk about `\linewidth` -- just use it instead of `\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% %%%
% Packages
% %%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose, a4paper, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm, lmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm} 
\usepackage{lipsum, enumerate, ifthen, tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}



% %%%
% Variable Settings
% %%%%
\newboolean{solution}
\setboolean{solution}{true}



% %%%
% Environments / Commandy
% %%%%
\newcommand{\Problem}[1]{
    {
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \textsf{\textbf{Problem #1}}
        \vspace*{0.2cm}
    }
}

\newenvironment{solution}
{
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{
        \tcolorbox[breakable, width=\linewidth, colframe=red, colback=white]
    }{}
}
{
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{
        \endtcolorbox
        \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    }{}
}



% %%%
% Document
% %%%%
\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \LARGE \sf \textbf{MWE}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{0.2cm}

    \Problem{1: Foo}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
            \begin{solution}
                \lipsum[4-5]
            \end{solution}

            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
                    \begin{solution}
                        \lipsum[4-4]
                    \end{solution}
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh dear, I'm dumb... Thank you my name fellow! :)

Comment: And I was creating an answer which calculates the `\linewidth` based on the `\leftmargin` and the `\textwidth`, man I'm dumb...

Comment: @Sam You're welcome! Now that this problem is solved, can you please go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: @Skillmon Your not `sam` enough for this question :)

Comment: @samcarter Obviously not, this feels horrible. I didn't even recognize that it's the `\linewidth` what I'm calculating (though my results looked fabulous! -- well, exactly like yours with just 3 lines more...)

Comment: @Skillmon It would be interesting if you would add this as an additional answer!

Comment: @samcarter it was based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365677/117050). So no, it wouldn't.

Comment: @samcarter You're absolutely right, I should accept the answers... I didn't even know there were as many that were not accepted. I'm an awful community member :( BUT: I've done it now! Thanks for the friendly reminder!

Comment: @Sam: In the meantime you forgot to accept samcarter's solution ;-)